# Azure PostgreSQL Not working with Qlik installation for QlogReader and QlogWriter User

Tags: postgresql, azure, qliksense

I'm trying to install qlik on with Azure PosgreSQL database.

the problem is that azure automatically generates the user name in the following format (username@hostname)  while on qlik uses only the (username)

my question is there a way to change the default for qlogs_reader and qlogs_writer user. I need to install qliksense with Azure PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Azure Database for PostgreSQL for the exact reasons you mentioned. What version of Qlik Sense are you using? Because you can build out the tables, etc, manually.